# HTML window.open causing port disappear from url

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am using react and trying to open new windows with a function `window.open` but the url that I am opening has a port number let say `https://example.com:9000/?params=abc123`, but the window that newly opened doesn't have the port, just `https://example.com/?params=abc123`.

Is there something that I could do to keep the port?

Function sample

```
const handleButton = async () => {
        showLoading();

        try {
            let uniqueId;
            const url = "/getuniqueid";

            uniqueId = (await postNew(url, {}));

            const newUrl = 'https://example.com:9000/'

            if (uniqueId.data) {
                const top = (screen.height - 600) / 2;
                const left = (screen.width - 1200) / 2;

                window.open(
                    newUrl + `another-url?uniqueid=${uniqueId.data}`,
                    "popup",
                    "width=1200,height=600,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,top=" + top + ",left=" + left
                );
            } else {
                throw { message: "Something went wrong. Please try again!" };
            }
        } catch (error) {
            changeErrorMessage(error.message);
        } finally {
            hideLoading();
        }
    };
```

Comment: you must be doing something wrong, can't reproduce your problem, but then, you've shown no code

Comment: The port doesn't just disappear on it's own. Are you certain the target url doesn't redirect? Is the real code different? I assume it's not example.com

Answer (score 1):

The port number is omitted from the URL if it is reserved by the protocol according to this documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/port

Port 9000 makes it to the list here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

Try using a non well-known port number.

Comment: no port 9000 is not a disabled port it will not automatically remove

Comment: so far this is might be the correct answer.
I tried 8080, it's working. 443 not working. But 21 is working (based on the Docs, it is supposed to be not working either)

Comment: @ryanadhi Another clue as to what ports are available to use in your current computer is to go to your System32 folder through command prompt (run as administrator) and run "netstat -ab" without double quotes. The ones with LISTENING state should be usable.